# How to display a pop up notification to the user using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf-2

I am developing an application which requires that user must be notified about some background events i.e. invitation from other user, reminder time out etc.

Whenever the event occurs the controller will be notified, and a small window should be displayed to the user.

How should I proceed to achieve this. Which technology / tool will help me. I am using jQuery, JSF 2.0 and Spring 3.0.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

this will give a notification similar to the stackoverflow

**jQuery**

```
$("#notification").fadeIn("slow").append('your message');
$(".dismiss").click(function(){
       $("#notification").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="notification" style="display: none;">
  <span class="dismiss"><a title="dismiss this notification">x</a></span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#notification {
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    width:100%;
    z-index:105;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:white;
    background-color:#FF7800;
    padding:5px;
}
#notification span.dismiss {
    border:2px solid #FFF;
    padding:0 5px;
    cursor:pointer;
    float:right;
    margin-right:10px;
}
#notification a {
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold
}
```

Also take a look at [mplungjan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6504602/how-to-display-a-pop-up-notification-to-the-user/6505869#6505869) on how to listen to server updates and message load

Comment: @ mplungjan thats great, but now i notice, the OP has asked for server-side help also

Comment: so the script needs to poll the server. No biggie. setInterval and $.get()

Comment: yes i'll update my answer. By the way i was wondering is there any way we can implement this without using setInterval(), i mean event triggerd by some other logic?

Comment: [Long poll](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling) or [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)

Answer (score 2):

**HTML:**

```html
<input type="button" id="pop" value="Submit"/>
<div id="popup">
  <div id="topbar"> TITLE..</div>
  <div id="content">Here is you content...</div>
  <input type="button" id="ok" value="OK"/>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
#popup { background:#ccc; -moz-border-radius: 10px; width:300px; height: 200px; padding: 5px; position: absolute; left: 50%; margin-left: -150px; z-index: 500; display:none }
#topbar { background:#ddd; -moz-border-radius: 10px; padding:5px; height:20px; line-height:20px }
#content { padding:5px; -moz-border-radius: 10px; text-align:center }
#ok { position: absolute; left: 140px; top: 180px }
```

**JQUERY:**

```js
$(function(){
    $('#pop').click(function(){
        $('#popup').fadeIn().css('top',$(document).height()/2);
    });
    $('#ok').click(function(){
        $('#popup').fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Comment: Fixed the css ID popup - added a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/mmANr/) subtracting the popup height is probably also a good idea

Answer (score 2):

Using code from [@Anu's suggestion - my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/xa23e/), you can simply add a poll

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".dismiss").click(function(){$("#notification").fadeOut("slow");});

  setInterval(function() {
    $.get("ping.jsp?userid=<%= userID %>",function(message) {
      if (message) $("#notification").fadeIn("slow").html(message);
    });
   ,10000);
})
```

the message could include a timestamp to see if you had notified earlier instead of sending an empty message if no notificati9on is needed

Alternatives: [Long poll](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling) or [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)

Answer (score 1):

[Jquery ui](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) dialog is what you are looking for. It will come in handy for you. Although there are lots of other plugin available. This is the simplest..

Comment: Actually looking at the other examples, the jQuery UI is not needed here at all.