# Showing error message on dialogue box in struts 2?

Tags: java, web-applications, struts2

i have a login form in Struts 2 which has username and password field. what i want is when user submit the form and if it is not a valid user, i want to show the error message in a dialogue box (instead of showing the error message in login form itself). Is there any tag available in struts 2 for this or somebody can point me to similar kind of brief example?

Comment: by dialogue you mean some sort of overlyay/lightox? and are you submitting your login form in usual way or by ajax.?

Comment: dialogue means kind of popup box.I am submitting the form in normal fashion as we do in struts 2 with action attribute

Answer (score 8, accepted):

put this in your login page(you are returning here right, on invalid login?)

```
<script>
   <s:if test="hasActionErrors()">
        showDialog("<s:actionerror/>");
   </s:if>
function showDialog(msg){
  //your logic to show dialog goes here
}
</script>
```

[Here is a post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6504707/456135) which explains how to design a notification similar to stack overflow. You can use this or any other modal dialog, there are many tutorials on how to show a modal dialog

Comment: Good solution, but **it will break** due to the markup generated (*and* also if the errors themselves contain double quotes). To make it work simply [use the code provided in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29793896/1654265).